# How can I export a 3D model from Blender to Unity and get the image textures to stick?

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, image-processing, 3d, blender

I made a playing card (ace of hearts) in Blender and it has two image textures: one on the face of the card and one on the back of the card. I tried to import this card into Unity using the .fbx extension type, but the card does not load in Unity with the image textures (it will only load with one image on one side if I force the image assignment. This is great, but also not so great since I still need to assign the other image to the other side of the card and it seems like Unity doesn't assign multiple textures to different object faces). I also tried baking the image textures to the card itself in Blender, but the baking failed (I probably did it wrong, honestly; I am very new to Blender). Does anyone have any ideas as to how I could import this card into Unity3D? Was I right to bake the images onto the card itself before exporting it to the .fbx file type? Thank you in advance!